# Web Workers in create-react-app: Jest error: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, web-worker

I used https://blog.logrocket.com/web-workers-react-typescript/ to build some simple Web Workers in an application created with create-react-app. In it, I have code like this:

```
const workerSimplerExample: Worker = useMemo(
    () => new Worker(new URL("../workers/simple-example.ts", import.meta.url), {type:"module"}),
    []
);
```

This generates a URL which works whether I'm in dev mode, or using the `build` directory in Production mode. However, no matter what I do, Jest throws errors when I run create-react-app's basic `npm test` or `yarn test`, with the error being: `SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`

Any solutions I've found, (of which there aren't many, and none are very confident,) involve changing Jest or Bable settings in ways create-react-app doesn't allow unless I eject.

Has anyone figured out how to have Web Workers in React without breaking Jest or ejecting create-react-app?

Comment: Does the error still happen if you add an empty export to the same file? Create React App's jest setup _should_ be using babel, so it should be compiling away this code...

Comment: My worker file ends in `export {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I figured out that I can isolate the call to `new URL()` and then replace the file which is loaded when Jest runs. Credit goes to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/5697#issuecomment-1068899210).

First, isolate `new URL()`. My file is located at `src/workers/simple-example-factory.ts`

```
const getWorker = (): Worker => {
    return new Worker(new URL('./simple-example', import.meta.url));
}

export default getWorker;
```

Then, create a test double at `src/workers/simple-example-factory.fake.ts` and use a static file path.

```
const getWorker = (): Worker => {
    return new Worker(new URL('./simple-example', ''));
}

export default getWorker;
```

Then, you can get an instance of the work in your JSX/TSX files like so:

```
import SimpleExampleFactory from "../workers/simple-example-factory";
...
const workerSimplerExample: Worker = SimpleExampleFactory();
```

**At this point, the worker should still work in the browser.** Now, to fix Jest, we have to tell it to load a different file. We can modify the Jest configuration through `package.json` when using create-react-app ([See documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration).)

`package.json`

```
{
...
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "workers/(.*)-factory": "<rootDir>/src/workers/$1-factory.fake.ts"
    }
  },
...
}
```